# Is it possible to use Appflow's Live Update's feature with manually installed APKs?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic7, ionic-appflow

I was curious to see how updates could be handled in the case where I don't want an app to be published in the Google Play Store. This is because the app is destined to be used by organizations rather than the public, so in order to save more money but also to avoid having the public install the application, they want the organizations to install the APK binaries manually.
So I wondered what I had to do in the case where there were updates needed to be published for those binaries.

I know Live Updates exist but as far as I've understood it's reserved for Google Play Store and App Store. Is there any way to use the Live Updates functionality for this app? If not, are there any solutions which allow for something similiar? I really wish people don't have to manually re-install the updated binary.